# Typescript Instantiate a class from it's generic type <T>

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I've got a generic hook, passing the type of the kind of object I want it to return to me, but I'me stucked cause I can't instantiate a class from it's generic type.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
export function useMyCustomHook<T>(): [data: string]{
  // some stuff here
  const foo = new T(...parameters); // how could I get something generic here, I'm gonna have multiple implementations passing a class object model differents

  return [data];
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this, I've tried a factory approach but with no success.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Antoine

Comment: You can use `T` as a value

Comment: I don't understand, how should I do that ?

Comment: I think they mean you *can't* use `T` as a value, because it is a type. You need to pass an argument of type `T` and use that. Remember that TS gets compiled to JS, so how would the JS know what `T` is?

Comment: Generics are not real, there types, you can't initiate a generic type, you will still need to pass a class, you can then use a type on this, you will also need to put a generic constraint on the type so Typescript will know it can call new etc...

Comment: This won’t work, types and stuff only exists on typescript, but once yow code compiles, all them types disappear. The only way this can work is if you create a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve my problem:

```
function factory<T>(GenericRowType: { new (...parameters): T }, ...parameters): T {
  return new GenericRowType(...parameters);
}

export function useMyCustomHook<T>(): [data: string]{
  // some stuff here
  const rowTyped: T = factory(GenericRowType, ...toolsFailuresHistoryRow, dateOfTheData);

  return [data];
}



const[data] = useMyCustomHook(RundeckToolFailures);
```

Answer (score 0):

normally TS functions are

```
function foo<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
```

or

```
function foo<Type>(arg: Type[]): Type[] {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}
```

are you doing something like this

```
class Name {
    firstName = 'John';
    lastName = 'Doe';
}

class Factory {
    create<T>(type: (new () => T)): T {
        return new type();
    }
}

let factory = new Factory();
let person = factory.create(Name);
```

As you can see, the special part is the type `(new () => T)` which describes a type with an empty constructor. The call to create is almost as simple as it can be and you can also add constraints to the generic type argument if needed.

Comment: I've seen this code on a post, but my problem is that I don't want to write the class on the last line, I'd like it to be dynamic. Or should I create glue in the Factory to return the correct constructor based on the name of the class include in the T ?